# Easiest way to prototype and share mobile apps

Tags: iphone, mobile, prototype

I am looking for an easy way to prototype and share mobile apps. I tried a few apps for the past couple of days. It looks like there are many out there. But my requirement is to be able to work on the prototype collaboratively with the clients.